# python wavebender module raspberry pi raspbian

Tags: python, audio, raspbian

I am trying to generate audio in python on my raspberry pi running raspbian, I am using the wavebender module, found here:
https://github.com/zacharydenton/wavebender

The example programs run in IDLE, but instead of audio being produced, random letters and symbols appear in random places across the python shell window.

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to pipe the output to aplay as stated by the webpage you posted:

`$ python examples/binaural.py | aplay`

The generated sound is shown as random chars since that's what aplay reads as input.